# Animation doesn't stop when handler is called

Tags: android

I have a system which works like this:
- I start a spinner animation in my view when a network request is fired.
- When the request finishes (within a AsyncTask) the Animation is stopped.

This works fine except when the display turns off because of lack of user action. This code won't work in this situation:

```
imgVwSpinner.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        imgVwSpinner.clearAnimation();
        imgVwSpinner.setImageResource(R.drawable.refresh);
    }
});
```

Is there a workaround to ensure the animation is cleared?

Answer (score 0):

you can flag the state in your handler , and check that state back in `onResume`